# Win7 NTFS - "wiped" folder remains visible and cannot be deleted

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have searched far and wide and cannot find a way to delete a folder which "does not exist" but visible in Windows Explorer in \Downloads

Scenario: I downloaded a video and it created a folder and put itself inside it. The folder name includes something like this - "some video file ...*..Lianne..*.." (this display here removed the underscore which exists between .. and .. on either side of the name seen here)

Because the video is a bit "bad" I wiped the folder using R.Wipe & Clean. The file has been wiped, but the folder remains. I tried various methods to remove it, but each time the system tells me

"Cannot find this item. This is no longer located in C:\users\mike\downloads" or similar.

I cannot wipe it again. I cannot move it into some other folder and delete it. I cannot do anything with it. I searched through the Windows registry but cannot find any reference to it.

Coincidentally, I installed a new C drive and figured the offending folder won't copy over when I mirrored the entire C drive, given the folder does not exist. But it did copy. So now I still have the folder in \Downloads with an offending name for the world to see (well, my family at least).

Any suggestions? I did try several options suggested here regarding a file.

Many thanks to anyone who will respond.

Mike

Comment: Did you try to create folder with same name?

Comment: It may be the folder has gone but explorer thinks it is still there. Did you refresh the explorer view using F5? How you tried logging off and on again? Have you tried a restart?

Answer (score 0):

Explorer can give these problems indeed, but luckily the good old command prompt usually can deal with these paths.

Open a command prompt.

Use cd to navigate to the path where you have your downloads. (the `_` is where you press enter)

```
C:\>cd users_

C:\Users>cd mike_

C:\Users\mike>cd downloads_

C:\Users\mike\Downloads>cd some<tab>
```

(press tab to autocomplete names, so you're sure it will find it. Already works after the first char. In case there are more results, press tab more than once to go to the next result.)

```
C:\Users\mike\Downloads\some video file_....lianne...._>_
```

from here you should be able to delete the files using `del *.*`

then type `cd ..` to navigate to the previous folder, and then delete the folder using rd some<kbd>tab</kbd> with autocomplete to remove the folder.

Comment: Thanks everyone
Davidenko - yes I was able to create a new folder with the same name. I added some files into it, then selected that new folder and the other non-existant one and tried delete and tried wipe. They disappear except for the problem folder.
DavidPostill - yes I did all these actions including cleaning the registry with CCcleaner, wiping free space etc
LPChip - thanks for your detailed answer. Problem is when I navigate to 
c:\Users\Mike\ and I try cd downloads, I can't get into it and get "The system cannot find the path specified"
Any ideas?

Comment: Type the command `dir` and see what the exact name for downloads is. you can of course also cd d `tab` to autocomplete that name.

Comment: I have been able to make the DOC commands work now and I can see the relevant folder I want to delete, but when I try, it says it cannot find the folder.

Comment: If that's the case, then it seems there's an error in the File Allocation Table.. Only a format can resolve this issue then. If Dos cannot find it, nothing will. Can you at least navigate to that folder using cd?

Comment: LPChip - thanks, yes I can get to the folder in DOS and cd, but when I try to delete it, it says cannot find it. Interestingly I had copied the entire SSD to a new bootable SSD and the same issue remains.

Comment: Yes, I got that from the question. Seems a format and not copying the files is the only way. Perhaps you can rename the folder using the `move` command in dos and then delete it through explorer.

Comment: LPChip - thanks for your thoughts, but formatting is a nightmare and it is the reason I created a mirror of the drive. By the way, I have NTFS. Re the folder, whatever I try to do, whatever the software or DOS commands, the basic error message is this folder does not exist, can't do anything. It's just a visual, it does not actually exist. Properties and checking its various tabs and options always shows zero or no such folder, no such location. Cannot change security level as it does not exist. But I see it.

Comment: Yes, an error in the file allocation table. I had it once on an external drive, and only a format would get rid of it.

Comment: You might be able to solve this one by downloading a tool that can edit the file allocation table, and mark the folder as deleted in there. I know these tools exist, but I do not have any experience with it. EDIT: chkdsk might fix this actually.

Comment: Thanks LPChip, solution found! I downloaded freeware "Unlocker" and it allowed me to remove the offending folder easily. Lesson learned? Beware of R-rated video file names!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permissions problem, or a problem where the folder may contain unusual characters that aren't visible, like a space at the end, or a foreign language character. The folder may also contain a hidden file that isn't being deleted, and so the folder can't be deleted.

Have you tried renaming the folder? If you can do that, then the problem is probably something hidden inside it.

On XP Pro and probably newer versions of Windows as well, you go in to folder options and turn off simple file sharing, and enable viewing of hidden and system files. Then you can see if there are any hidden files in the folder. Delete everything. If you can't, right click on the folder and go to properties, then security, Advanced if need be, and take ownership and clear the permissions on everything in the folder.

It could also be malware or other software that's recreating the folder after you delete it. Check the creation date of the folder. If you right click and select delete, you should get some kind of error if Windows Explorer isn't actually able to delete it. Again, try to rename the folder.

I didn't realize that you had found a solution by using Unlocker. Since that worked, it means that there was some software accessing the folder which prevented you from doing anything with it. Maybe my answer will still help someone else who came here from a search engine.